# Dynamic forms with Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/addtopic.css">
    <div class="main">
            {% if acctype == "teacher" %}
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.topicname }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.contents }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.contents }}
                    </div> 
                </form>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
    </div>
```

I tried to make dynamic forms where the contents part can have multiple input boxes but I dont know how to actually use it
heres the forms

```py
class ContentForm(FlaskForm):
    section = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])

class ExerciseForm(FlaskForm):
    exercise = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    testcase = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])

class AddTopicForm(FlaskForm):
    topicname = StringField('Topic Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=100)])
    contents = FieldList(FormField(ContentForm), min_entries=1)
    exercises = FieldList(FormField(ExerciseForm), min_entries=0)
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it dynamic in that I click a button and one more input field pops up, and when I submit I get all the data?

Comment: I cannot help you with an example (as I haven't used them before), but I am aware of something called `hidden fields`, which might be what you are looking for. You create one form, send it to the HTML and implement it, but the fields that are hidden can be revealed with a button press. Again, I don't know fully but it's a direction I can point you in.

Comment: I can try but its not something I want, since I want them to just add more fields if they needed more

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread what you meant. Never mind then, hope you find a solution

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22219319/12488201